# Newton Raphson iteration - unable to iterate

Tags: fortran, precision, floating-accuracy, newtons-method

I am not sure this question is on topic here or elsewhere (or not on topic at all anywhere). 
I have inherited Fortran 90 code that does Newton Raphson interpolation where logarithm of temperature is interpolated against logarithm of pressure.

The interpolation is of the type

```
t =  a ln(p) + b
```

and where a, b are defined as

```
a = ln(tup/tdwn)/(alogpu - alogpd)
```

and

```
 b = ln T - a * ln P
```

Here is the  test program. It is shown only for a single iteration. But the actual program runs over three FOR loops over k,j and i. In reality pthta is a 3D array(k,j,i) and thta is a 1D array (k)

```
 program test

 implicit none
 integer,parameter :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(12,307)
 real(kind=dp)  kappa,interc,pres,dltdlp,tup,tdwn
 real(kind=dp)  pthta,alogp,alogpd,alogpu,thta,f,dfdp,p1
 real(kind=dp) t1,resid,potdwn,potup,pdwn,pup,epsln,thta1
 integer i,j,kout,n,maxit,nmax,resmax


 kappa = 2./7.
 epsln = 1. 
 potdwn = 259.39996337890625
 potup =  268.41687198359159
 pdwn = 100000.00000000000
 pup =  92500.000000000000
 alogpu =  11.43496392350051
 alogpd =  11.512925464970229
 thta = 260.00000000000000
 alogp = 11.512925464970229
 ! known temperature at lower level
 tdwn = potdwn * (pdwn/100000.)** kappa
 ! known temperature at upper level 
 tup = potup *(pup/100000.)** kappa
 ! linear change of temperature wrt lnP between different levels
 dltdlp = dlog(tup/tdwn)/(alogpu-alogpd)
 ! ln(T) value(intercept) where Pressure is 1 Pa and assume a linear
 ! relationship between P and T
 interc = dlog(tup) - dltdlp*alogpu
 ! Initial guess value for pressure

 pthta = exp((dlog(thta)-interc-kappa*alogp)/(dltdlp-kappa))
 n=0

 1900 continue
 !First guess of temperature at intermediate level
 t1 = exp(dltdlp * dlog(pthta)+interc)
 !Residual error when calculating Newton Raphson iteration(Pascal)
 resid = pthta - 100000.*(t1/thta)**(1./kappa)
 print *, dltdlp,interc,t1,resid,pthta

 if (abs(resid) .gt. epsln) then
   n=n+1
 if (n .le. nmax) then
    ! First guess of potential temperature given T1 and
    ! pressure level guess
    thta1 = t1 * (100000./pthta)**kappa
    f= thta - thta1
    dfdp = (kappa-dltdlp)*(100000./pthta)**kappa*exp(interc + (dltdlp -1.)*dlog(pthta))
    p1 = pthta - f/dfdp
    if (p1 .le. pdwn) then
       if (p1 .ge. pup) then
          pthta = p1
          goto 1900
       else
          n = nmax
       end if
    end if
 else
    if (resid .gt. resmax) resmax = resid
    maxit = maxit+1
    goto 2100
 end if
end if

2100 continue

end program test
```

When you run this program with real data from a data file the value of resid is the following

```
2.7648638933897018E-010
```

and it does not differ much for the entire execution. Most of the values are in the range

```
1E-10 and 1E-12
```

So given these values the following IF condition

```
IF (abs(resid) .gt. epsln)
```

never gets called and the Newton Raphson iteration never gets executed. So I looked at two ways to get this to work. One is to remove the exponential call in these two steps

```
pthta = exp((dlog(thta)-interc-kappa*alogp)/(dltdlp-kappa))

t1 = exp(dltdlp * dlog(pthta)+interc)
```

i.e. keep everything in the logarithmic space and take the exponent after the Newton Raphson iteration completes. That part does converge without a problem.

The other way I tried to make this work is to truncate

```
t1 = exp(dltdlp * dlog(pthta)+interc)
```

When I truncate it to an integer the value of resid changes dramatically from 
1E-10 to 813. I do not understand how truncating that function call leads to such a large value change. Truncating that result does result to a successful completion. 
So I am not sure which is the better way to proceed further.

How can I decide which would be the better way to approach this ?

Comment: Note that the kappa `2./7.` is computed in single precision only. The same holds for other constants like  `259.39996337890625`, they are truncated to single precision. The code is not very nice.

Comment: @VladimirF - I almost guessed you would jump on it and I hesitated to ask for this reason :) . It is poorly written code but a thesis was defended using this code and the scientific idea is worthy of publication. Hence I am trying to make something out of it

Comment: If you have inherited a small piece of code that doesn't work, sometimes the best approach is to throw it away and start with a clean sheet of paper and write it yourself.

Comment: @agentp - that is the same suggestion given by a colleague. But the overall question remains if I decide to rewrite it - should I do the NR in logarithmic space or in exponential space ?

Comment: Since your question is rather research-oriented, my general opinionated research-oriented answer is: one should always work with the logarithm of the properties of the system that are by-definition always positive, in your case, temperature and pressure. Strictly positive-definition physical variables often result in overflow and underflow in computation, whether you use Fortran or any other programming language, or any variable kind. If something can happen, it will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a research perspective, I'd say your first solution is likely the more appropriate approach. In a physical simulation, one should always work with the logarithm of the properties that are by-definition always positive. In the above code, these would be temperature and pressure. Strictly positive-definite physical variables often result in overflow and underflow in computation, whether you use Fortran or any other programming language, or any possible variable kind. If something can happen, it will happen.

This is true about other physical quantities as well, for example, energy (the typical energy of a Gamma-Ray-Burst is ~10^54 ergs), volume of objects in arbitrary dimensions (the volume of a 100-dimensional sphere of radius 10meters is ~ 10^100), or even probability (the likelihood function in many statistical problems can take values of ~10^{-1000} or less). Working with log-transform of positive-definite variables would enable your code to handle numbers as big as ~10^10^307 (for a double precision variable).

A few notes also regarding the Fortran syntax used in your code:

- The variable `RESMAX` is used in your code without initialization.
- When assigning values to variables, it is important to specify the kind of the literal constants appropriately, otherwise, the program results might be affected. For example, here is the output of your original code compiled with Intel Fortran Compiler 2018 in debug mode:

  ```
    -0.152581477302743        7.31503025786548        259.608693509165
    -3.152934473473579E-002   99474.1999921620
  ```

  And here is the same code's output, but with all literal constants suffixed with the kind parameter `_dp` (see the revised version of your code below):

  ```
    -0.152580456940175        7.31501855886952        259.608692604963
    -8.731149137020111E-011   99474.2302854451
  ```

  The output from the revised code in this answer is slightly different from the output of the original code in the above question.
- There is no need to use `.gt.`, `.ge.`, `.le.`, `.lt.`, ..., for comparison. These are legacy FORTRAN syntax, as far as I am aware. Use instead the more attractive symbols ( `<` , `>` , `<=` , `>=` , `==` ) for comparison.
- There is no necessity to use a `GOTO` statement in a Fortran program. This is again legacy FORTRAN. Frequently, simple elegant do-loops and if-blocks can replace `GOTO` statements, just as in the revised code below.
- There is no need to use kind-specific intrinsic functions in Fortran anymore (such as  `dexp`, `dlog`, ... for double precision). Almost all (and perhaps all)  of Fortran intrinsic functions have generic names (`exp`, `log`, ...) in the current Fortran standard.

The following is a revision of the program in this question, that resolves all of the above obsolete syntax, as well as the problem of dealing with extremely large or small positive-definite variables (I probably went too far in log-transforming some variables that would never cause overflow or underflow, but my purpose here was to just show the logic behind log-transformation of positive-definite variables and how to deal with their arithmetics without potentially causing overflow/underflow/error_in_results).

```
program test

implicit none
integer,parameter :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(12,307)
real(kind=dp)  kappa,interc,pres,dltdlp,tup,tdwn
real(kind=dp)  pthta,alogp,alogpd,alogpu,thta,f,dfdp,p1
real(kind=dp) t1,resid,potdwn,potup,pdwn,pup,epsln,thta1
integer i,j,kout,n,maxit,nmax,resmax

real(kind=dp) :: log_resmax, log_pthta, log_t1, log_dummy, log_residAbsolute, sign_of_f
real(kind=dp) :: log_epsln, log_pdwn, log_pup, log_thta, log_thta1, log_p1, log_dfdp, log_f
logical :: residIsPositive, resmaxIsPositive, residIsBigger

log_resmax = log(log_resmax)
resmaxIsPositive = .true.

kappa = 2._dp/7._dp
epsln = 1._dp 
potdwn = 259.39996337890625_dp
potup =  268.41687198359159_dp
pdwn = 100000.00000000000_dp
pup =  92500.000000000000_dp
alogpu =  11.43496392350051_dp
alogpd =  11.512925464970229_dp
thta = 260.00000000000000_dp
alogp = 11.512925464970229_dp

log_epsln = log(epsln) 
log_pup =  log(pup)
log_pdwn = log(pdwn)
log_thta = log(thta)

! known temperature at lower level
tdwn = potdwn * (pdwn/1.e5_dp)**kappa
! known temperature at upper level 
tup = potup *(pup/1.e5_dp)** kappa
! linear change of temperature wrt lnP between different levels
dltdlp = log(tup/tdwn)/(alogpu-alogpd)
! ln(T) value(intercept) where Pressure is 1 Pa and assume a linear
! relationship between P and T
interc = log(tup) - dltdlp*alogpu
! Initial guess value for pressure

!pthta = exp( (log(thta)-interc-kappa*alogp) / (dltdlp-kappa) )
log_pthta = ( log_thta - interc - kappa*alogp ) / ( dltdlp - kappa )

n=0

MyDoLoop: do

    !First guess of temperature at intermediate level
    !t1 = exp(dltdlp * log(pthta)+interc)
    log_t1 = dltdlp * log_pthta + interc

    !Residual error when calculating Newton Raphson iteration(Pascal)
    !resid = pthta - 1.e5_dp*(t1/thta)**(1._dp/kappa)
    log_dummy = log(1.e5_dp) + ( log_t1 - log_thta ) / kappa
    if (log_pthta>=log_dummy) then
      residIsPositive = .true.
      log_residAbsolute = log_pthta + log( 1._dp - exp(log_dummy-log_pthta) )
    else
      residIsPositive = .false.
      log_residAbsolute = log_dummy + log( 1._dp - exp(log_pthta-log_dummy) )
    end if

    print *, "log-transformed values:"
    print *, dltdlp,interc,log_t1,log_residAbsolute,log_pthta
    print *, "non-log-transformed values:"
    if (residIsPositive) print *, dltdlp,interc,exp(log_t1),exp(log_residAbsolute),exp(log_pthta)
    if (.not.residIsPositive) print *, dltdlp,interc,exp(log_t1),-exp(log_residAbsolute),exp(log_pthta)

    !if (abs(resid) > epsln) then
    if ( log_residAbsolute > log_epsln ) then
        n=n+1
        if (n <= nmax) then
            ! First guess of potential temperature given T1 and
            ! pressure level guess
            !thta1 = t1 * (1.e5_dp/pthta)**kappa
            log_thta1 = log_t1 + ( log(1.e5_dp)-log_pthta ) * kappa
            !f = thta - thta1
            if ( log_thta>=thta1 ) then
              log_f = log_thta + log( 1._dp - exp( log_thta1 - log_thta ) )
              sign_of_f = 1._dp
            else
              log_f = log_thta + log( 1._dp - exp( log_thta - log_thta1 ) )
              sign_of_f = 1._dp
            end if
            !dfdp = (kappa-dltdlp)*(1.e5_dp/pthta)**kappa*exp(interc + (dltdlp -1._dp)*log(pthta))
            ! assuming kappa-dltdlp>0 is TRUE always:
            log_dfdp = log(kappa-dltdlp) + kappa*(log(1.e5_dp)-log_pthta) + interc + (dltdlp -1._dp)*log_pthta
            !p1 = pthta - f/dfdp
            ! p1 should be, by definition, positive. Therefore:
            log_dummy = log_f - log_dfdp
            if (log_pthta>=log_dummy) then
                log_p1 = log_pthta + log( 1._dp - sign_of_f*exp(log_dummy-log_pthta) )
            else
                log_p1 = log_dummy + log( 1._dp - sign_of_f*exp(log_pthta-log_dummy) )
            end if
            !if (p1 <= pdwn) then
            if (log_p1 <= log_pdwn) then
               !if (p1 >= pup) then
               if (log_p1 >= log_pup) then
                  log_pthta = log_p1
                  cycle MyDoLoop
               else
                  n = nmax
               end if
            end if
        else
            !if (resid > resmax) resmax = resid
            residIsBigger = ( residIsPositive .and. resmaxIsPositive .and. log_residAbsolute>log_resmax ) .or. &
                            ( .not.residIsPositive .and. .not.resmaxIsPositive .and. log_residAbsolute<log_resmax ) .or. &
                            ( residIsPositive .and. .not. resmaxIsPositive )
            if ( residIsBigger ) then
                log_resmax = log_residAbsolute
                resmaxIsPositive = residIsPositive
            end if
            maxit = maxit+1
        end if
    end if

    exit MyDoLoop

end do MyDoLoop

end program test
```

Here is a sample output of this program, which agrees well with the output of the original code:

```
log-transformed values:
 -0.152580456940175        7.31501855886952        5.55917546888014
  -22.4565579499410        11.5076538974964
 non-log-transformed values:
 -0.152580456940175        7.31501855886952        259.608692604963
 -1.767017293116268E-010   99474.2302854451
```

For comparison, here is the output from the original code:

```
 -0.152580456940175        7.31501855886952        259.608692604963
 -8.731149137020111E-011   99474.2302854451
```